# Unable to install couchbase via pip: 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h' file not found

Tags: python-3.x, couchbase

I am having some trouble installing couchbase dependencies.

First I installed v2 using brew:

```
brew install libcouchbase@2
```

This gave me v2.10.7. Then I tried to install the version I need:

```
pip install couchbase==2.5.5
```

But I keep having this issue:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
...
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/.../.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/include/python3.6m -c src/exceptions.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/src/exceptions.o
In file included from src/exceptions.c:17:
src/pycbc.h:193:10: fatal error: 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h' file not found
#include <libcouchbase/couchbase.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution! I had to run the following command:

```
brew link --force --overwrite libcouchbase@2
```

And then I got:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libcouchbase@2/2.10.7... 77 symlinks created
```

After this I ran:

```
pip install couchbase==2.5.5
```

And it worked fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it gave you this error because libcouchbase was not installed. Try to re-install it without "@2" at the end.

```
brew install libcouchbase
```

After that re-install with pip.

```
pip install couchbase==2.5.5
```

Comment: I had similar error :( my first attempt was to ignore @2 and I got v3 after all. The difference is I was getting 'libcouchbase/api3.h' file not found error without the @2 :(

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation: https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/2.5/start-using-sdk.html you need to install libcouchbase before installing the 2.x Python SDK to resolve this issue.

I would highly recommend installing the newer 3.x Couchbase Python SDK as this prerequisite is no longer needed.